# Devemos sempre marcar uma questão com tag de linguagem quando uma está envolvida?

Tags: debate, tags, big-7

Eu sei que isso está bem definido em outros sites. Mas aqui pode ser decidido que seja diferente. Não que eu ache que deva ser, o ideal é que mantenha o padrão do SO para facilitar o modelo mental entre os sites para quem participa de ambos.

Por exemplo, a questão [Erro: R cannot be resolved](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54/android-r-cannot-be-resolved) claramente fala sobre uma solução em Java e não tem [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Por outro lado tem [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) que pode indicar que seja Java, mas não necessariamente. O texto indica bem que é sobre Java mas as tags servem para organizar o conteúdo independente do texto. Não se atenha  muito a esse exemplo, é só o que vi agora para ilustrar um caso. A questão não é sobre esse caso.

Como devemos proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu creio que há pelo menos duas formas de pensar:

1. **Tags abrangentes**: usar o maior número de tags possível. A vantagem é que a pergunta vai ter uma maior visibilidade, mas ao mesmo tempo pode atingir um público alvo indesejado.
2. **Tags específicas**: usar apenas as tags relacionadas diretamente com o assunto. Evita *spam* de tags, mas pode falhar em atingir o público desejado.

Porém, existem casos, como no exemplo citado (Android + Java), onde tudo isso fica mais confuso. O desenvolvimento era para Android, a mensagem era um erro de compilação do Java, mas o problema era da IDE. Em situações assim talvez o melhor seja deixar todas as tags, pois estão envolvidas todas essas variáveis.

Por outro lado, existem algumas tags que são complicadas por natureza devido a sua abrangência. Vou citar um exemplo pessoal. Eu sou desenvolvedor Java, mais para a parte JEE. Porém, se eu acessar o feed da tag Java vão ter muitos assuntos fora do meu campo de conhecimento, como Android ou Arduino. Infelizmente não há muito o que fazer nesses casos, mas eu sou a favor de usar a tag Java simplesmente porque Java já é uma "grande categoria".

Comment: Eu usei o exemplo, que não foi o melhor, quando me deparei com ele justamente porque me pareceu algo com várias facetas, e faltou deixar claro na taxonomia que também era sobre Java. Mas a questão sobre qualquer situação mesmo.

Comment: Acabei aceitando esta porque a prática mostra que é mais ou menos isto que está sendo sendo tratado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu sempre fui fã de usar a tag mais específica possível. Marcar somente como [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) uma pergunta sobre [django](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) pode até aumentar a quantidade de pessoas que poderiam ver o post, mas a maior parte delas provavelmente não teria condição de avaliar a questão corretamente.

Mesmo que uma tag específica vá diminuir o público, você aumenta a chance de alguém ter passado pelo mesmo problema.

No exemplo citado (pergunta sobre [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), mas que talvez pudesse ser resolvida por qualquer um que usasse a mesma IDE) usar [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) talvez pudesse ajudar, mas também faria sua pergunta competir com muito mais posts pela atenção de alguém.

Todo mundo tem um ponto específico de interesse dentro de uma área maior. Acho que ser bem específico nas tags é o melhor jeito de conseguir ajuda de gente mais capacitada a resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Acho que a decisão sobre isso é o mais importante mesmo. O exemplo realmente não foi bom, é o que eu vi e me chamou a atenção.

Comment: Não acredito que exista a necessidade de uma política formal em relação a isso, muito menos agora... Acho que vale mais como conselho de que efetivamente sair editando posts (ou punindo usuários) porque eles não usaram as tags "corretas"

Comment: Concordo quanto a isso. A questão é mais como orientação geral de como deve ser.